# Svg Fit Canvas to Drawing via C#

Tags: c#, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to split and SVG into many different SVG files each one containing one element original file.

My main problem is not the slipt in itself since for each element I have to split, I get the svg element, remove everything else from the original svg, add back the element into the main layer and then save the file with the name I want. This works fine.
The real problem is that each file I create has the view centered and dimensioned as in the original svg file. So usually it's misplaced and wide (since in the original file it would contain all elements that now are split into different files). 
So I need to resize the canvas to the element that remains in the file.

This very function is done by inkscape with the command

**inkscape --verb=FitCanvasToDrawing --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose**

But unfortunally this verb doesn't work in --without-gui mode, so if I call it in the code I see thousands of inkscape instances opening, fitting the canvas and then save and close the windows. It works but it's not good for a batch application (they have this "bug" since quite some years).

So I resorted to use SVG engine (https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) but it has a bug that prevents the right calculation of the element bounds (https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/issues/331), so I cannot change the viewbox or the svg element to the right values.

Any suggestion on how to calculate the right position and size? Or any other library (any language that can run in a batch) that works for that?

Comment: Self-promotion: I've written a node module that seems to do exactly what you want to achieve: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-icon-toolbox. Workflow: 1.[Pre-process](https://github.com/ccprog/svg-icon-toolbox/blob/master/lib/iconize-svg.js#L60) existing viewBox information. 2. Call [`inkscape -S`](https://github.com/ccprog/svg-icon-toolbox/blob/master/lib/iconize-svg.js#L225) to produce a list of bounding boxes for all element. 3. Make a copy and remove every other element 4. [rewrite](https://github.com/ccprog/svg-icon-toolbox/blob/master/lib/iconize-svg.js#L236) viewBox.

Comment: Tnx, will check it

Comment: It seems you use Inkscape for find out the bounding boxes... that's what I need to do via code... Tnx anyway